# Вывод данных из базы в Combobox

Tags: sql, c++builder

Мне необходимо создать запрос на выборку наименований складов (поле `DESCR`) из таблицы (`SC53`). Затем необходимо прочитать все эти наименования (я делаю это как `Query1->Fields[i][0]->AsString`) и добавить в `Combobox1`. Ошибка в `Query1->Fields[i][0]->AsString`, но я не знаю, как правильно записать.

```
Query1->SQL->Text = "SELECT DESCR FROM SC53";
Query1->Active = true;
Query1->Open();
ComboBox1->Items->Clear();
for(int i=0; i < Query1->RecordCount; i++)
    ComboBox1->Items->Add(AnsiString(Query1->Fields[i][0]->AsString));
```

Answer (score 1):

`Query1->Active = true;` и `Query1->Open();` это одно и то же, поэтому 1-е лишнее.

`Query1->Fields[i][0]->AsString` - такого не бывает. Может быть `Query1->Fields[i]->AsString`. А в случае из вопроса в коллекции `Fields` вообще всего один элемент.

Для наибольшей наглядности должно быть что-то типа `Query1->FieldByName('DESCR')->AsString`.

А, вообще, проход по источнику данных лучше всего делать так:

```
ComboBox1->Items->Clear();
Query1->SQL->Text = "SELECT DESCR FROM SC53";
Query1->Open;
try{
    Query1->First;
    while( !Query1->Eof ){
        ComboBox1->Items->Add( AnsiString(Query1->FieldByName('DESCR')->AsString) );
        Query1->Next;
    }
}finally{
    Query1->Close;
}
```